# How to Find Open Polygons via PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

How can I detect polygons / loops which are not topologically closed?  I'm not wanting to fix any open polygon / loop.  I merely just wish to identify them.

I do know that for a polygon to be "valid" it must be closed when using st_IsValid.  But an invalid geometry doesn't mean it's an open polygon.

I've been able to use st_IsValidDetail to help me find things like self-intersections, but now I just want to simply identify features which are not topologically closed.

I believe st_IsValidDetail should be able to do this for me quite easily if I know the correct reason to filter for.

The problem I run into is I do not know where online I can find a list of all the reasons for an invalid geometry as reported by st_IsValidDetail.  Is there a comprehensive list somewhere?

Comment: Such non-closed features must have zero area.

Comment: @user30184     Is it possible to have some other value for an open polygon?

Comment: Read through the tests in the source code: http://data.gd.no/lib/geos-3.4.2/tests/unit/capi/GEOSisValidDetailTest.cpp.

Comment: @user30184     So I used the following PostGIS query:  "SELECT ogc_fid, ST_IsValidDetail(geom) FROM LayerName WHERE ST_Area(geom) = 0"     I get one match out of an 11GB ESRI GDB file.  In the back of my mind I have to wonder if there are other cases where something is a topologically open polygon / loop with an undefined area but not explicitly 0.

Comment: I don't really understand how such open polygons can be created even if your data comes from OpenStreetMap where polygon relations are more or less hand-written. In traditional GIS such topology errors are not common at all. Well, Oracle that is using the tolerance model "if vertices are within a tolerance we consider them the same even coordinates are not exactly same" might give such cases if data are exported into other formats.

Comment: @user30184     I don't either, but they exist... the files I'm QAing come from many different vendors via many different file formats.  A lot of hands in the cookie jar and potential for conversion snafus.  I'm basically trying to identify invalid geometries by category and throw things back to the vendor to resolve.

Answer (score 3):

A non-closed polygon will return the following value for `ST_IsValidReason`:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring
```

Such geometries are difficult to create, since PostGIS' WKT parser does not allow you to construct a non-closed polygon geometry.  But the WKB parser has no such restrictions, and you can create one by corrupting an existing closed geometry:

```
 SELECT 
   left(encode(ST_AsBinary('POLYGON ((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 0))'::geometry), 'hex'), -1) || '1';
```

Here, I've replaced the last hex character of the WKB representation, causing the last point to shift and not match the original.  If you were to run `ST_IsValidReason` on this, you'd indeed see:

```
SELECT ST_IsValidReason((left(encode(ST_AsBinary('POLYGON ((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 0))'::geometry), 'hex'), -1) || '1')::geometry);
                                st_isvalidreason                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 IllegalArgumentException: Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring
```

A footnote: When calculating area, PostGIS assumes that rings are closed and ignores the last coordinate entirely.  So for the invalid geometry above, `ST_Area` returns `0.5`, as if the last coordinate had been the same as the first.

Comment: I just so happened to be coming to the same conclusion, but the reason seems to be slightly different.  I'm getting:  "IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of points in LinearRing found 3 - must be 0 or >= 4"  This is the result of looking for polygons with an area of 0.  Having said that, I've tried to filter exclusively on the reason and I don't seem to be able to get PostGIS to take the substring of the reason.  Do you by chance know how I can tell it something like:  "SELECT ogc_fid, ST_IsValidDetail(geom) FROM LayerName WHERE reason(ST_IsValidDetail(geom)) = '???'"

Comment: @George `WHERE (ST_IsValidDetail(geom)).reason = 'xxx'` or, more simply, `WHERE ST_IsValidDetail(geom) = 'xxx'`

Comment: I guess I was asking more about the literal string to search for.  I do get the same result as looking for an area of 0 using the string "Invalid number of points in LinearRing found 3 - must be 0 or >= 4"... I get no such match using the string "Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring"... what's the difference if there is any between the reasons / errors stated?  Is this the same error / reason but different due to versioning?

Comment: Based off of your footnote, would I be better off checking to see if the starting coordinate point == ending coordinate point to come to the conclusion of an open polygon?  I may have gotten tunnel vision on this in trying to get IsValidDetail to give me a reason to filter for.  Do you see a reason why checking starting and ending points would not cover all cases of an open polygon / loop?

Comment: @George `ST_IsValidReason` is reporting the first validity error it found. 
 It's possible that your cases of "Invalid number of points in LinearRing" are also non-closed.  You could update your query to filter on either of the two reason messages.